# Allow specified apps write access to external sd card in kitkat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, external-sd

Is it possible - and if so what options are there - to allow only some apps access to all files on the external SD card in KitKat on a rooted device?

I see the value in proper permissions on the SD, but I'd really like to let a couple of apps have free reign.

Specifically, ES file explorer is fine as I've granted it root and it seems able to do anything.

But I like using FX file explorer and the root integration there isn't as easy to use as ES. And I like folder sync and would like it to do some internal to external SD syncs.

Is there a way to just grant some apps full write access to the external SD without opening it to all users?

I wonder about using titanium to turn an app into a system app. Or adding a group to the list which has write permissions, but I have no idea how to maintain the users and groups on my phone.

Comment: This is pretty close to the SD card permissions introduced in android 5 I think, when my devices get updates I should be able to do this OOTB.